# How can I convert curl request to WebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, php, wcf, curl, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to convert curl request to `WebRequest` in C# but not able to get the response as it always returns 401 unauthorized error

[image]

Here is the working curl request:

> curl -k -v https://api.demo.peertransfer.com/v1/transfers -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"provider\":\"HUL\",\"payment_destination\":\"hult-applicationfee\",\"amount\":\"29000\",\"callback_url\":\"http://studentapplication.local/en/nextsteps\",\"callback_id\":\"abc1234546asas\",\"dynamic_fields\":{\"student_id\":\"32453245\",\"student_first_name\":\"Candy\",\"student_last_name\":\"Student\"}}" -H "X-Peertransfer-Digest: zYUt+Pn0A06wsSbCrrbAZn68Aslq9CbSUAKBrUEwIzI="

Output:

[image: This is actual result i need to get in webrequest]

The result in the red box is what I need to get in `WebRequest` Response,
here is my C# code

```
private void testnewfunc()
{
    string value = "{\"provider\":\"HUL\",\"payment_destination\":\"hult-applicationfee\",\"amount\":\"29000\",\"callback_url\":\"http://studentapplication.local/en/nextsteps\",\"callback_id\":\"abc1234546asas\",\"dynamic_fields\":{\"student_id\":\"32453245\",\"student_first_name\":\"Candy\",\"student_last_name\":\"Student\"}}";
    var URI = new Uri("https://api.demo.peertransfer.com/v1/transfers");
    byte[] data = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
    var requst = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
    requst.UserAgent = "curl/7.43.0";
    requst.Method = "POST";
    requst.KeepAlive = true;
    requst.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    requst.ContentType = " application/json";
    requst.ContentLength = data.Length;
    // wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    requst.Accept = "*/*";
    //Or any other encoding type.
    string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(data);          

    var uname = "hultdemo2015";
    var pword = "gEejgC0GF8pCbI7C";
    var creds = string.Format("{0}:{1}", uname, pword);
    creds = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creds));

    requst.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", creds);            
    requst.Headers["X-Peertransfer-Digest"] = string.Format("{0}", "zYUt+Pn0A06wsSbCrrbAZn68Aslq9CbSUAKBrUEwIzI=");
    using (Stream stream = requst.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)requst.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        //Now you have your response.
        //or false depending on information in the response
        // return true;
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm making wrong in the `WebRequest`.

Comment: You have no `Authorization` header in your `curl` example. How are you being authorized for that?

Comment: curl request's are sent without Authorization header's. @Cᴏʀʏ

Comment: But the API requires credentials for the C# code? That seems odd. Everything in your `WebRequest` looks good, but I would figure out exactly what/whether you need the `user-agent` and `authorization` headers. That's where your `WebRequest` differs from the curl request.

Comment: Let me remove user-agent and authorization from headers and try @Cᴏʀʏ

Comment: I removed those but still the same, no success :( @Cᴏʀʏ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = false });

var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://api.demo.peertransfer.com/v1/transfers"));
message.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
message.Headers.Add("X-Peertransfer-Digest", "zYUt+Pn0A06wsSbCrrbAZn68Aslq9CbSUAKBrUEwIzI=");
message.Content = new StringContent("{\"provider\":\"HUL\",\"payment_destination\":\"hult-applicationfee\",\"amount\":\"29000\",\"callback_url\":\"http://studentapplication.local/en/nextsteps\",\"callback_id\":\"abc1234546asas\",\"dynamic_fields\":{\"student_id\":\"32453245\",\"student_first_name\":\"Candy\",\"student_last_name\":\"Student\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(message);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status Code: {0}{1}Content-Type: {2}{1}Date: {3}{1}Location:{4}", responseMessage.StatusCode, Environment.NewLine, responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType, responseMessage.Headers.Date, responseMessage.Headers.Location));
```

And here's the response from the server (same as curl):

[image]

**Version compatible with .Net 4.0**

```
var data = "{\"provider\":\"HUL\",\"payment_destination\":\"hult-applicationfee\",\"amount\":\"29000\",\"callback_url\":\"http://studentapplication.local/en/nextsteps\",\"callback_id\":\"abc1234546asas\",\"dynamic_fields\":{\"student_id\":\"32453245\",\"student_first_name\":\"Candy\",\"student_last_name\":\"Student\"}}";

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://api.demo.peertransfer.com/v1/transfers"));
request.Method = "POST";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.Headers.Add("X-Peertransfer-Digest", "zYUt+Pn0A06wsSbCrrbAZn68Aslq9CbSUAKBrUEwIzI=");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(reqStream))
{
    writer.Write(data);
}

var response = request.GetResponse();
MessageBox.Show(response.Headers.ToString());
```

Make sure you include these using statements:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
```

and these are the response headers from the server:

[image]